# JQuery enabling checkbox on div scroll

Tags: jquery, html, checkbox, scroll

A while ago I was here to find out [how to enable a checkbox on scroll down of a div][1].

Everything was fine and it all worked. Though several months later it stops working and I can't figure out why.

By "stops working" I mean when I scroll down to the bottom of the div now the checkbox remains disabled.

There is no response and no apparent errors

I just want a scrollable div to enable a checkbox when the user scrolls to the bottom of the div.

```
            <script>
            $( document ).ready( function() {
             $('#terms').scroll(function () {
              if ($(this).scrollTop() == $(this)[0].scrollHeight - $(this).height()) {
                alert('dfdsafds');
                $('#payment').removeAttr('disabled');
                }
             });
            });
            </script>
            <h4><a href="JavaScript:cartPopup('tnc.php')">Terms and Conditions of Sale</a></h4>
            <p>In order to continue with your online purchase, you must agree to the terms and conditions of sale. <a href="JavaScript:cartPopup('tnc.php')">Click here</a> to view the terms and conditions of sale.</p>
            <div id="terms">
                <p>
                     Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. In nec vulputate felis, sed dignissim neque. Cras sit amet metus consectetur, ultricies ligula ac, imperdiet turpis. Nulla bibendum viverra velit, nec aliquam ipsum malesuada et. Aenean condimentum sollicitudin dolor, eget suscipit velit. Sed ultrices suscipit hendrerit. Fusce facilisis tellus ac pulvinar rutrum. Aenean semper lacus erat, vitae dignissim mauris faucibus sit amet. Pellentesque mattis leo vitae nisi dignissim, at lobortis risus feugiat. Vestibulum convallis mi ac hendrerit tempus. Maecenas vitae ligula ligula. Mauris nec egestas ipsum. Donec blandit ante in elit porttitor, eu pretium massa tempor. Vestibulum eu sapien lacus. Aliquam at interdum nisl. Nulla aliquam ante at est ullamcorper tristique. Vestibulum aliquet pharetra blandit. 
                </p>

                <p>
                     Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. In nec vulputate felis, sed dignissim neque. Cras sit amet metus consectetur, ultricies ligula ac, imperdiet turpis. Nulla bibendum viverra velit, nec aliquam ipsum malesuada et. Aenean condimentum sollicitudin dolor, eget suscipit velit. Sed ultrices suscipit hendrerit. Fusce facilisis tellus ac pulvinar rutrum. Aenean semper lacus erat, vitae dignissim mauris faucibus sit amet. Pellentesque mattis leo vitae nisi dignissim, at lobortis risus feugiat. Vestibulum convallis mi ac hendrerit tempus. Maecenas vitae ligula ligula. Mauris nec egestas ipsum. Donec blandit ante in elit porttitor, eu pretium massa tempor. Vestibulum eu sapien lacus. Aliquam at interdum nisl. Nulla aliquam ante at est ullamcorper tristique. Vestibulum aliquet pharetra blandit. 
                </p>
            </div>
            <form style="width:800px;float:left;" action="<?=$PHP_SELF;?>" method="post">
                <input id="payment" type="checkbox" disabled name="terms"> <span class="redSmall">I confirm I have read and agree to the terms and conditions. (Must be ticked to continue)</span>
            <!-- PayPal Logo --><img style="float:right;" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/webstatic/mktg/logo/AM_SbyPP_mc_vs_ms_ae_UK.jpg" width="170" border="0" alt="PayPal Acceptance Mark"><!-- PayPal Logo -->
                <p>Select Payment Method</p>

                <select id="paymentType" name="payment" style="width:200px;">
                    <?php if(isset($_SESSION['username']) && $_SESSION['userActive'] == 1){?><option value="2">Account</option><?}?>
                    <option value="1">PayPal</option>
                </select>                   
            </form>
```

Does anybody see a problem here that I am missing? At the moment scrolling the div does not enable to checkbox.

Here is a little debugging info.

If I place a javascript alert beneath this line `$( document ).ready( function() {`

It alerts successfully on page load. So far so good

If I place an alert beneath this line `$('#terms').scroll(function () {`

It alerts successfully when I try to scroll the div down any amount. So far so good.

When I place it inside this IF statement `if ($(this).scrollTop() == $(this)[0].scrollHeight - $(this).height()) {`

Nothing happens. Which tells me the conditions of the IF are not being met. But this code works on CodePen or JSFiddle and I can not see any problems.

Comment: > stops working - what exactly is happening, checkout the console for errors.

Comment: Amended my question to say what happens. But basically nothing happens. When I scroll to the bottom of the div the checkbox doesnt enable. It remains disabled and there are no apparent errors. A little debugging tells me it is not getting to the Jquery because I cant even send out an alert() on scroll

Comment: Try to log to console values `$(this).scrollTop()`, `$(this)[0].scrollHeight` and `$(this).height()`

Answer (score 1):

```
$(window).scroll(function()
{
    if ( $(this).scrollTop()  >= $("#terms").height())
    {
          $('#payment').prop({disabled: false});
    }
});
```

---

[**EXAMPLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/Ivoss/3sg16L8s/1/)

Answer (score 0):

```
$(window).scroll(function()
{
    if (document.body.scrollHeight - $(this).scrollTop()  <= $(this).height())
    {
          $('#payment').prop({disabled: false});
    }
});
```

---

[**EXAMPLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/Ivoss/3sg16L8s/)

Comment: This would work for the whole screen scroll. Not the particular div containing the terms and conditions. Which is only a small box.

Comment: @Kevlar see you new answer

Answer (score 0):

I actually cannot find a misstake. I tried you code and it's working for me.
    http://codepen.io/anon/pen/RNMExm

I added a CSS rule to make the `<div>` scrollable, maybe that was the solution...
If do not want to have this rule you should not check the scrolling of the div but of the body.

Comment: I know I can not see anything wrong. But for some reason it doesn't work. The div is already scrollable I have CSS for that already

Comment: Does my CodePen work for you? Can you provide the complete code to check the sources (jQuery)?
Maybe you could create a Codepen or JSFiddle Document, so it is editable.

Comment: Yes your CodePen works and when I use CodePen it also works. I have amended my question to include my code as it is in my file